# Opencart 3.0.3.x changes in some controllers has no effect

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, opencart

I had to start learning Opencart (I'm a newbie) as I just got an Opencart webshop with VQMod to redesign it. The previous developer hardcoded some things, and God knows what else happens in the code.
My problem is that changes in some controllers take effect, while some don't. For example:

> url: */index.php?route=account/login
> catalog/controller/account/login.php:

```
class ControllerAccountLogin extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('account/customer');
        exit;
...
```

This has zero impact; it renders without any problem. It doesn't matter whether I exit, insert valid or invalid code. But the same changes in:

> url: */index.php?route=account/login
> catalog/controller/common/header.php:

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('setting/extension');
        exit;
```

or

> url: */index.php?route=account/account
> catalog/controller/account/account.php

or

> url: */index.php?route=common/home
> catalog/controller/common/home.php

Do exit the code. The same thing happens with the corresponding models. Changes in models, some take effect, while some don't. It does not matter what I try; changes in some controllers simply have no effect. It's like (to me) the changed controllers/models wouldn't be loaded at all.

I deleted all caches, including VQMod manually and OC on-site, but I don't think it's a caching issue. 
What can be the problem, what should I look for?

Comment: Do not enough to delete caches. You also need refresh modifications on OC admin.

Comment: It works, thanks. I had been looking for asnwer for 2 days.